# Proof of the mass conservation property for the Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to prove that the mass is conserved for the Fokker-Planck equation.
I know that the Fokker-Planck equation can be written as a continuity equation:

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}+\nabla \cdot J=0 .
$$

where we define $J$ as the vector whose $i$ th component is

$$
J_{i}:=a_{i}(x) p-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(b_{i j}(x) p\right) .
$$

According to references on the web, if we integrate the FP equation over $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and integrating by parts on the right hand side of the equation we should get:

$$
\frac{d}{d t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} p(x, t) d x=0 .
$$

implying the conservation of mass. However I don't seem to be able to show that without knowing anything more for $a_i$ and $b_j$. Can someone help me see that? Thanks!

Comment: Divergence Theorem

Comment: thanks for the reply! I don't see how to apply divergence theorem as I am integrating over $R^d$ here. It also seems to me that $a_i$ and $b_j$ would need to be related to get zero.

Comment: The divergence theorem applies just the same in $\mathbb R^N$ as in $\mathbb R^3$.

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{\mathbb R^N}p(t,x)\mathrm d^N x=\int_{\mathbb R^N}\partial_tp(t,x)\mathrm d^N x \\ \text{(Leibniz rule)}$$

Then
$$=\int_{\mathbb R^N}(\nabla\cdot J)(t,x)\mathrm d^n x \\ =\lim_{r\to\infty}\int\limits_{\mathbb B(0,r)}(\nabla\cdot J)(t,x)\mathrm d^N x \\ =\lim_{r\to\infty}\oint\limits_{\partial\mathbb B(0,r)}(n\cdot J)(t,x)\mathrm d^{N-1}x$$ 
After this you need more information about $J$.

Comment: I agree that it seems like more information is needed for $J$. However it is mentioned in several places in the literature of Fokker Planck that it conserves mass. ( such as in this pdf: https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/lec_fokker_planck.pdf ) and in Pethame's book in Parabolic Equations in Biology pg 146. So I am wondering if there is a way to prove that for the equation with any $J$.